# how to add SVG graphic to pdf document using iText 7 in c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, svg, itext7

I'm working on generator of stickers, using iText7 C#.
The look of the final sticker is to look like this:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=16q_sMP5H0eiVhq85DDRGgE-CDlX3fOB5

I've problem with adding SVG graphic to pdf document. I have graphics in above link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bw2E5hVhKjjwYqn6aGbe_tNqPmYmXu4b
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lEqhrh2zAlOGlA1WMKfGtuhue6TBtcbc

I can not find any practical example on the Internet how to read an SVG file and add to a pdf document using iText7.

Can anyone help me with this topic?

Comment: SVG is XML.  The images would be Base 64 bit strings.  So you would need to parse the xml and convert Base 64 string to byte[] and then to bit images.  The images could also be URL links and you may need to get the images from the links.

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest release 7.1.4, you would add an SVG to a document like this:

```
public static void Convert(Stream svg, Stream pdfOutputStream) {
        SvgConverter.CreatePdf(svg, pdfOutputStream);
}
```

There are many other possibilities in this class to convert to PDF, but this is the easiest method to use.

Answer (score -1):

I use this code to add SVG graphic to pdf document:

```
string enc_text = File.ReadAllText(SVG);                            
SvgConverter.DrawOnCanvas(enc_text, pdfCanvas);
```

but it's work only for simple SVG graphics like below
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_ellipse3

don't work for this SVG created and saved in CorelDraw:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bw2E5hVhKjjwYqn6aGbe_tNqPmYmXu4b/view
is that possible to draw this graphic on pdf using itext7 C#?

Comment: Without trying to convert that one: it looks like it should be supported though... Which version are you using? Have you upgraded to the latest version? Does it throw an exception or log a warning?

Comment: thanks for your response. I use the latest  version 7.1.4. iText. There is no exceptions and warnings

Answer (score -1):

This is Code:

```
public const String SVG = @"C:\Users\Desktop\logo.svg";
```

....

```
string enc_text = File.ReadAllText(SVG);                            
SvgConverter.DrawOnCanvas(enc_text, pdfCanvas);
```

I tried three times and below are results:

**Attempt 1
SVG**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ibg_KwvviRQ4b9suniZwBJRdBdgM02te
**PDF - the result is: OK:**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DGGLUowlEYpAydbWTTSJORVxP67LGrf5

**Attempt 2
SVG:**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UHASgAxAaPONIo9fc6VZ9q4cjjK-uOzj
**PDF - the result is: half well**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yzLF-fQQcOQvEXVyDN-UuK0YVeHOn5B_

**Attempt 3
SVG** 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZNLDkc2x4WvHouKw-A4AgRrDuQ2pAoDE
**PDF  - the result is: no logo**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nJVNT5oAMoI8HuUURZQv1yhu7IbFoI6H

SVG graphics are well displayed in browsers, but iText can not draw them properly, especially those complicated